Custom Sidebar content expects "i.stack.imgur" link despite the change over to i.sstatic.net
Update:
Now, it seems it expects the PhotoUrl to begin with https://i.static.net/ (note the singular "s" in the URL).  However, the photo URLs have two s's.  So it still doesn't work.


Arqade has a custom sidebar content section (and I believe Photography SE does as well) that allows us to put an image on it. This custom sidebar can be updated by site moderators which I am one.
However, when I tried to update it, it will not let me since it expects the PhotoUrl to begin with https://{imgur}/.  According to Stack Exchange’s image hosting arrangement with Imgur is ending - advance notice, SE no longer uses i.stack.imgur.  This tool should be updated to allow the new image hosting URL or both of these URLs (for backwards compatibility - I don't see why not at least) (looks like the imgur images will be transitioned, so we don't need to support both URLs).


The 'update' part no longer applies, correct?

@Mast I guess technically none of the post does? But that's why I posted an answer. Doesn't quite make sense to post the "answer" I the question right? That was my thoughts.

I just checked today (May 21st 2024) and it seems this works again. It allows i.sstatic.net URLs for the PhotoUrl.
A mod/staff member can mark this as status-completed.
